# Get frames from the video saved in the photo directory iphone?

Tags: iphone

HI All.

how can i get the frames of any video that i am fetching from the photo directory iphone .I checked out various links but they only provide any thumbnails or any particular TIME's frame image but i need the frames of full length video .And the respective audio too then is that possible that from the freames i got and the audio file i can create another video but will change the sequence of the frames only the audio file will be the same in the video.Is that feasible .?

Sample code or link will be more helpful !!!

Thanks,
Balraj,

Answer (score 2):

Visit [Codza](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone) and check out [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Do not forget to see https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor